# jQuery: fadeTo/fadeOut items from a PHP Loop

Tags: jquery, each, fadeout, fadeto

So I am completly new to jQuery. And I have been trying with this all day without any success yet.

I have a php loop containing divs and what I want to do is to fadeIn the first item, fade it out, then fadein the next and so on.

So far I have come up with this:

- The php loop write out the divs in a other div with the id `#container`
- I then use the css `position:absolute` to give the items the same position. And then `opacity:0.0` to make them all hidden at start.

And then it was time for jQuery for fadeIn/fadeOut. Since I start with opacity 0.0 it seems that I can not use fadeIn so I use fadeTo instead. I then figured I had to asign ID's to all the div's since I dont know how many items the loop contains. And then use .each to fadeTo/fadeOut each item.

But I can't get it right. Obviously I am doing some thing wrong.

This is the jQuery I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '#container div' ).each( function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'item-'+(i+1) );
    });

    $( '#container div' ).each( function(i) {
        $( '#item-'+(i+1) ).fadeTo(3000, 1).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

I should also say, that in this case I can't asign ID with the PHP loop, and then get them with jQuery. The Id's need to be asign using jQuery.

Comment: Point is - you don't need ids to make slideshow. JQuery is great because easier traversing through DOM: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ Also, there are some great solutions, like: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ If this is for learning purpose, we can try to debug your code...

Comment: Hi, Yes this is for learning purpose. So as simple and well explaind code example would be best  :) And yes, I don't need to use id's I just asumed that was the way to do it. If there is a better sulotion I am up for it  :)

Comment: Np, of course. Do you need continual slideshow, e.g. at the end - return to start? I could modify your solution/approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of countless solutions:

```
function slide() {
$( '#container div:first' ).fadeTo(3000, 1).fadeTo(1000,0, function() {
$( "#container" ).append( '<div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>' );
$(this).remove();
});
}

setInterval(slide,1000);
```

To get idea what is happening here, check demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1xzw6fw0/, and turn on inspector and inspect HTML (F12 on Win systems, i am using Web developer tools in Firefox).

Idea is: fade in JUST first element in container, then when it is hidden/animation complete/opacity:0 - you see additional function as parameter of fadeTo() - that function append it to the END of container, and removes current element from DOM, so now first element is last, second is first, etc, etc...

Hope you got it? And at the end - we will call function slide() every second - you can change it to fit your needs...

Comment: This was a very smart way of solving this, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7rpdeph/1).

HTML:

```
<div id='cntr'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <!-- ... etc ... -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cntr { background: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; }
#cntr div { position: absolute; width: 90px; height: 90px; left: 5px; top: 5px; opacity: 0; }
#cntr div:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
#cntr div:nth-child(2) { background: green; }
#cntr div:nth-child(3) { background: gray; }
#cntr div:nth-child(4) { background: purple; }
#cntr div:nth-child(5) { background: orange; }
#cntr div:nth-child(6) { background: yellow; }
```

Then it's just a case of kicking off a sequence of timeouts, one per item (it will work for any number of child elements), based on the desired animation duration multiplied by the index of the child.

In other words, if our anim duration is 500 (ms) the first child (index 0) begins immediately (500 x 0); the second child after 500ms (1 x 500), the third after 1 second (500 x 2) and so on.

```
var animDuration = 1000;
$('#cntr div').each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, animDuration);
    }.bind(this), i * animDuration);
});
```

Comment: This only "fadin" elements, and not fadeout?

Comment: I had figured that, since the divs all overlayed each other, fadeIn was all you needed. After all, when the next div fades in, the one behind is invisible. You can adapt it as required. I've still given you a sound basis for progression.

Comment: Well I am trying to make it fadeout too :)

Comment: When only fading in, things become a bit "messy" if it would contain text for example if a other div still overlays with some opacity :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#container div').each(function (index) {
    $(this).prev().fadeOut();
    $(this).delay(600*index).fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/lacumejiga/1/

Comment: This does'nt work at all for me, nothing happens (fadin/fadout)?

Comment: And what is the purpose of delay(600*index)? Why not just delay(600)?